# Make Table with Long and wrapped text for Table Header

Tags: tables

I want to make table like this [image: table]

Here's my code (only try with the header and one empty row)

```
\begin{table}[ph]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{\textwidth}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
      \hline
      No & Uraian Tugas & Nama Kegiatan & Tahapan Kegiatan & Proses Kegiatan Aktualisasi dan Keterkaitan dengan NDS & Output/Hasil  Kegiatan & Kontribusi Output/Hasil Kegiatan terhadap Penguatan NDS Organisasi & Hambatan yang Mungkin akan Dialami dalam Mengaktualisasikan NDS & Solusi Menghadapi Hambatan \\
      \hline 
       & & & & & & & & &
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, this is what I get

[image: table that I get]

Please help.

Comment: You have a `&` that shouldn't be here in the second line and tabular environnement does not accept the size you can use tabularx instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Use a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment.
- Use a column type that permits wrapping of long material.
- Load the `babel` package with the appropriate language setting. (In the example below, I set "indonesian", but I may be completely wrong.
- Choose a smaller font size, and reduce the amount of whitespace that's inserted between columns.
- Write `\slash` instead of `/` if you want LaTeX to insert line breaks at the slash symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}    % choose appropriate language
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set page paramaters

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ph]
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt
  \footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|*{8}{Y|}}
      \hline
      No & Uraian Tugas & Nama Kegiatan & Tahapan Kegiatan & Proses Kegiatan Aktualisasi dan Keterkaitan dengan NDS & Output\slash Hasil  Kegiatan & Kontribusi Output\slash Hasil Kegiatan terhadap Penguatan NDS Organisasi & Hambatan yang Mungkin akan Dialami dalam Mengaktualisasikan NDS & Solusi Menghadapi Hambatan \\
       \hline
       & & & & & & & &  \\
       \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```